# Java generics and wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Let's say I have these classes:

```
class A<T> {
  void set(T t) {}
}

class B<T> {
  T get() { return null; }
}

class C extends A<String> { }
class D extends B<String> { }

class E extends A<Long> { }
class F extends B<Long> { }
```

And these variables:

```
A<?> a1 = new C();
B<?> b1 = new D();

A<?> a2 = new E();
B<?> b2 = new F();
```

Can I do these somehow (with some magic?):

```
a1.set(b1.get());
a2.set(b2.get());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But you can do

```
A<String> a1 = new C();
B<String> b1 = new D();

A<Long> a2 = new E();
B<Long> b2 = new F();

a1.set(b1.get());
a2.set(b2.get());
```

`A<?>` means *A of some class, but I don't know which one*. So you can't call its `set()` method because the compiler doesn't know if the type of the argument matches with the actual generic type of A.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot because you have

```
A<?> a1 = new C();
B<?> b1 = new D();
```

is the same as

```
A<? extends Object> a1 = new C();
B<? extends Object> b1 = new D();
```

So the generic type of `a` is a wildcard or unknown. b1.get() is an `Object`, a1.set() takes an unknown subclass of Object.

```
A<String> a1 = new C();
B<String> b1 = new D();
a1.set(b1.get()); // is okay as the type is `String`
```

Comment: I tried to experiment with A<Object> z = (A<Object>)a1; z.set(b1.get()) seems to work. Would this cause any problems?

Comment: Why use generics if you don't care about type safety? Doing that is basically the same as removing the generic type, and accepting any kind of Object as argument.

Comment: Well, that was kind of my question, if I could do it (safely) without type safety, sorry for being a little unclear. So, without type safety, I can do that the way I want. It's just that the existing API returns wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

You want to transform 1 kind of object to another object. Try [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Please check the wiki link for more inside to adapter pattern.

Create an Adapter class which transforms your Object B to Object A.

```
class MyAdapter
{


public static A adaptTo(B b)
{
//your code to transform B to A

}

}
```

Now when you want to transform B to A, simply call

```
A a = Adapter.adaptTo(b);
```

Comment: Where is the translation? `b1.get()` returns a String and `a1.set()` takes a String.

Comment: @PeterLawrey He has to implement that logic in adapter class method.

Comment: Why does he need to if the types are the same?

Comment: @PeterLawrey His types are not same. classes A and B are independent. He has not mentioned that types of both classes will be same at runtime.

Comment: "b1.get() returns a String and a1.set() takes a String." That is same enough for me (and the JVM)

Comment: Yes, as Peter Lawrey said, I meant the type parameters will be the same.